# Convert List to 2D Array (Java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner in programming and I have a method :

```
 public int[][] toArray(List<Integer> list, int rows) {
        int[][] result = new int[list.size()][rows];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
            for (Integer value : list) {
                result[i][j] = value;
                j++;
                if(j > rows - 1){
                    i++;
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        return result;
    }
```

The result of it, if `rows = 2` (and if we have a list contains numbers from 1 to 7) is:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

If `rows = 3` result is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

**What I need**:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 0]] 

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 0, 0]]
```

How to do that?

Comment: `int[][] result = new int[rows][(int)(list.size()/rows)];` might be better. Usually a doubly dimensioned array is int[rows][columns].

Comment: By using a debugger or print statements or even better a piece of paper and a pen... To observe what the code is doing. Your learn such  things by working on them till you find the solution. Sometimes that takes hours. Detours don't help you.

Comment: columns = size / rows

Comment: @Brianbcr666Ray with `int[][] result = new int[rows][(int)(list.size()/rows)];` I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line of code:

```
int[][] result = new int[list.size()][rows];
```

As you are initializing the result to a 2D array having rows equals to list.size() you are getting always seven rows. The solution is to first compute the number of rows for result array properly and then initialize it.

```
int resultRows = list.size()/rows;
if(list.size()%rows!=0){
    resultRows++;
}
int[][] result = new int[resultRows][rows];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's another approach using Streams and Guava:

```
public static int[][] toArray(List<Integer> list, int rows) {
    return Lists.partition(list, rows)
            .stream()
            .map(Ints::toArray)
            .map(a -> Arrays.copyOf(a, rows))
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: The approximate speed of your method (in `nanoseconds`) with list contains numbers from 1 to 7 and `rows = 3` is: 38321. My method (with @mesbah help) showed the result: 5135.

Comment: You might want to read up on premature optimization and microbenchmarking in Java before throwing around figures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `counter` to track the count and determine the position by `counter/rows` and `counter%rows`, e.g.:

```
public int[][] toArray(List<Integer> list, int rows) {
    int[][] result = new int[list.size()][rows];
    int counter = 0;
    for (Integer value : list) {
        result[counter/rows][counter%rows] = value;
        counter++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You don't need to worry about remaining places as all the `MxN` elements get initialised with 0 when you declare an array with size.